# SharePoint related PowerShell tutorials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am really interested in PowerShell for **SharePoint Administration**. Please help me with some books, sources or tutotials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great sample of PowerShell scripts developed/managed by Microsoft MVPS and employees for SharePoint farms (WSS or MOSS) management.

http://sharepointpsscripts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

A great PowerShell primer is [PowerShell in Action](http://www.manning.com/payette/) by Bruce Payette.

A great PowerShell w/ SharePoint primer is [Automating SharePoint w/ PowerShell 2.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470939206) by Gary Lapointe and Shannon Bray

[Gary Lapointe's blog](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/) is also very good with many sample scripts.

Comment: _Automating SharePoint with Powershell 2.0_ is an amazing reference book and must have for SharePoint Admins.

Answer (score 3):

For using PowerShell with SharePoint - there are tools, code libraries and some good books out there:

[Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Command Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html)

[SharePoint Management PowerShell scripts (CodePlex)](http://sharepointpsscripts.codeplex.com/)

[Automating SharePoint 2010 with Windows PowerShell 2.0 (book)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470939206,miniSiteCd-SYBEX.html)

[PowerShell for SharePoint 2010 How-To (book)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067233559X)

[PowerShell for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administrators (book)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071747974)

[Microsoft SharePoint 2010 and Windows PowerShell 2.0: Expert Cookbook (book)](http://www.packtpub.com/microsoft-sharepoint-2010-and-windows-powershell-2-0-expert-cookbook/book)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great blog on using PowerShell with SharePoint:
http://get-spscripts.com/

Answer (score 2):

For Real-World SharePoint PowerShell scripts:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/search/label/PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

There is a PowerShell command builder tool for SharePoint developed by Microsoft. It has been of great help to me. Try it: [Windows Powershell Command Builder for SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html)